# How to invoke an executable file several times from within a DOS batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to write an MS-DOS batch file that accepts one mandatory argument `%1`. This argument specifies the number of times I invoke an executable file from within the batch file.

Shortly speaking, how to invoke the executable file (e.g., `pdflatex.exe`) `%1` times from within the batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for-loop.

Syntax:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%1) DO pdflatex.exe
```

For more info on For-loops in a Batch-file, use Google: batch for

Comment: Excuse me, how can I call, for example, `mspaint.exe` multiple times without closing the previous open one? The current code that you gave makes only one application open after closing the previous one.

Comment: +1 @AdorableCreature Use `DO start pdflatex.exe` to get multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a basic loop:

check this site here:

http://tom.paschenda.org/blog/?p=26

```
echo off
SET /a i=0

:loop
IF %i%==%1 GOTO END
    pdflatex.exe
SET /a i=%i%+1
GOTO LOOP

:end
```